# find duplicate columns and replace matches with count

Tags: c#, regex, ssis

I have a tab delimited file which has duplicate named headings;

```
[Column1] \t [Column2] \t [test] \t [test] \t [test] \t [test] \t [Column3] \t [Column4]
```

What I want to do, is re-name the columns that are duplicated [test] with a integer.
So would become something like

```
[Column1] \t [Column2] \t [test1] \t [test2] \t [test3] \t [test4] \t [Column3] \t [Column4]
```

So far, I can isolate the first row.  Then count the matches I have found

```
string destinationUnformmatedFileName = @"C:\New\20130816_Opportunities_unFormatted.txt";
string destinationFormattedFileName = @"C:\New\20130816_Opportunities_Formatted.txt";
var unformattedFileStream = File.Open(destinationUnformmatedFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);  // Open (unformatted) file for reading
var formattedFileStream = File.Open(destinationFormattedFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);   // Create (formattedFile) for writing

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(unformattedFileStream);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(formattedFileStream);

int rowCounter = 0;
// Read each row in the unformatted file
while ((currentRow = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //First row, lets check for duplicate names
    if (rowCounter = 0)
    {

    // Write column name to array
    string delimiter = "\t";
    string[] fieldNames = currentRow.Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());

    foreach (string fieldName in fieldNames)
    {
        // fieldName must be followed by a tab for it to be a duplicate
        // original code - causing the issue
        //Regex rgx = new Regex("\\t(" + fieldName + ")\\t");
        // Edit - resolved the issue
        Regex rgx = new Regex("(?<=\\t|^)(" + fieldName + ")(\\t)+");   

        // Count how many occurances of fieldName in currentRow
        int count = rgx.Matches(currentRow).Count;               
        //MessageBox.Show("Match Count = " + count.ToString());

        // If we have a duplicate field name 
        if (count > 1)                                           
        {
             string newFieldName = "\t" + fieldName + count.ToString() + "\t";
             //MessageBox.Show(newFieldName);
             currentRow = rgx.Replace(currentRow, newFieldName, 1);   
         }
     }
     }
rowCounter++;
}
```

I think I'm on the right track, but I don't think the regex's are working correctly?

Edit:  I think I have figured out how to find the pattern with using;

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("(?<=\\t|^)(" + fieldName + ")(\\t)+");
```

Its not a deal breaker, but only problem now is that it labels;

```
[Column1] \t [Column2] \t [test4] \t [test3] \t [test2] \t [test] \t [Column3] \t [Column4]
```

Instead of

```
[Column1] \t [Column2] \t [test1] \t [test2] \t [test3] \t [test4] \t [Column3] \t [Column4]
```

Comment: "I don't think the regex's are working correctly" sounds like you're not even sure whether there's a problem at all. What's not working? Do you get exceptions? Wrong results? No results? Also, you might want to use verbatim strings for your patterns to avoid double escaping: `@"\t(`. Secondly, you should probably run `fieldName` through `Regex.Escape()` before concatenating it into a pattern, because it could potentially contain metacharacters.

Comment: Regarding your edit. If that fixes it then the problem was that matches can never overlap. Since you required a `\t` before and after your field name, matches of adjacent fields would overlap. The lookaround is a good fix for that. Also, please post your solution as an answer (and accept it if you don't get a better one).

Comment: Thanks m.buettner - I have posted answer but need to wait 2 days to accept it.  Feel bad now wasting peoples time should of waited a bit longer and researched a bit more.  Thanks for help!

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)" and "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the below

```
 Regex rgx = new Regex("(?<=\\t|^)(" + fieldName + ")(\\t)+");
```

Resolved the problem by using a lookaround which I found here;
http://www.regular-expressions.info/duplicatelines.html

Possibly should of spent a few more minutes researching it before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Test your regex at [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) first. I think "\t" is a special character. Try "\\t".
In your C# it would be "\\\\t"

Comment: He did, and it wouldn't matter anyway. The regex engine can deal with an actual tab character as well as an escaped `\t`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **great** combination between `Regex` and `LINQ`:

```
var input = @"[Column1] \t [Column2] \t [test] \t [test] \t [test] \t [foo] \t [test] \t [Column3] \t [foo] \t [Column4]";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?<=\\t )[[](.+?)[]]");
string output = "";
int k = 0;           
foreach (var m in reg.Matches(input)
                     .OfType<Match>()
                     .Select((x,i)=>new {x,i})
                     .GroupBy(g=>g.x.Value)
                     .Where(g=>g.Count()>1)
                     .SelectMany(x=> x.Select((a,i)=>new {a,i=i+1}))
                     .OrderBy(x=>x.a.i)){                        
     output += input.Substring(k, m.a.x.Index - k) + m.a.x.Result("[${1}" + m.i + "]");
     k = m.a.x.Index + m.a.x.Length;
 }
 output += input.Substring(k);
```

Result:
**[Column1] \t [Column2] \t [test1] \t [test2] \t [test3] \t [foo1] \t [test4] \t [Column3] \t [foo2] \t [Column4]**